# Customizing the SharePoint 2010 Blog Post page

Tags: blog, sharepoint-designer

Can I customize the blog template pages in SharePoint 2010 Foundations? I found some articles online about editing the schema located in the 14Hive folder. I'd rather not do this, can it be done through SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a site definition based off the blog template:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg276356.aspx

or a better way is to utilize feature stapling, where you can inject your customization for just about anything, including changing master pages.

http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1065